# Where can I see my Leave Closed votes?

Tags: support, review, activity

I would like to see again those questions in which I voted for *Leave Closed*, in my *Reopen Votes* reviews.

I've seen the *Votes* section of my *Activity* page, but I don't see those posts found there.

Is there a place where I can find my *Leave Closed* votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying "Leave Closed" or "Leave Open" in the review queues does not cast a vote. They are only review actions.

You can see these in your "All actions" section of your profile (in the same bar where you found Votes) and can further filter to the Reviews type. But it is not possible to filter further by review queue or action, and any post that has since been deleted will not show up in that list.